# @RestContollerAdvice not throwing custom exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, exceptionhandler, controller-advice

I am using Spring Boot 3 to develop a simple Rest API and want to handle exceptions using @RestControllerAdvice, but my code is throwing a 500 error even if the code in @exceptionHandler is throwing a 404 error code. I verified in debugging that execution reaches the ExceptionHandler method, but the default exception is still thrown.

Below is sample code for:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ControllerExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public Messsage resourceNotFoundException(ResourceNotFoundException exception, WebRequest request) {
        return new Messsage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value(), exception.getMessage(), LocalDateTime.now());
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public Messsage globalException(Exception exception, WebRequest request) {
        return new Messsage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value(), exception.getMessage(), LocalDateTime.now());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`  .
which some ExceptionHandler has defined  and  it may catch exception before you custom exceptionHandler.
I had made some   unit test  here is code sample;

- Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AccountApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AccountApplication.class);
    }
}
```

- Controller

```java
/**
 * @author pengpeng
 * @description
 * @date 2023/2/13
 */
@RequestMapping
@RestController
public class AccountController {

    @GetMapping("/test/{args}")
    public String testError(@PathVariable ("args") String args) throws IllegalAccessException {
        if (args .equals("ill")){
            throw new IllegalAccessException();

        } else if (args.equals("exception")) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }else {
            return "success";
        }
    }

}
```

- exceptionHandler

```java
/**
 * @author pengpeng
 * @description
 * @date 2023/2/13
 */
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ControllerException extends ResponseEntityResultHandler {


    public ControllerException(List<HttpMessageWriter<?>> writers, RequestedContentTypeResolver resolver) {
        super(writers, resolver);
    }

    public ControllerException(List<HttpMessageWriter<?>> writers, RequestedContentTypeResolver resolver, ReactiveAdapterRegistry registry) {
        super(writers, resolver, registry);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public String illegalFail(IllegalAccessException exception){
        return "illegalFail";
    }



    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_GATEWAY)
    public String fail(Exception exception){
        return "fail";
    }
}
```

after application start  use the default  application port to initiates  HTTP call

- http

```
127.0.0.1/test/ill
127.0.0.1/test/exception
127.0.0.1/test/success
```

Comment: Hi Peng, Thank you for your response! I have tried with and without extending ResponseEnttiyResultHandler but it does not work any way. Please see below my Controller code for reference:

Comment: @ RestController
@ RequestMapping("/api")
public class VesselController {
    @Autowired
    private VesselService vesselService;
    @PostMapping("/vessels")
    public ResponseEntity<Vessel> addVessel(@RequestBody Vessel vessel) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        try {
            vesselService.createVessel(vessel);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException(e.getMessage());
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(vessel, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}

Comment: not sure the code ``` vesselService.createVessel(vessel);  ``` will thrown the exception which will be captured by try ... catch try to thrown ```ResourceNotFoundException``` directly
if the example not work in correct way ,you shoud check your  SpringApplication
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class VesselController {
    @PostMapping("/vessels")
    public ResponseEntity<Vessel> addVessel(@RequestBody Vessel vessel) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```